# Variable scoping in Swift with tasks

Tags: ios, swift, scope

I've got all of this code inside of a function in my view controller:

```
self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "PUT"

var err: NSError?
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(["notes": self.textView.text], options: nil, error: &err)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
var s = NSString(data: request.HTTPBody!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, reponse, error) -> Void in

    // ------------------
    // This doesn't work
    // ------------------
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()


    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
})
task.resume()
```

I want my activity indicator to stop animating when I am finished with my task, but calling stopAnimating() isn't doing anything - not even throwing any errors. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do that on the main UI Thread like this:

```
    // ------------------
    // This should work :-)
    // ------------------
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        // DO SOMETHING ON THE MAINTHREAD
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform it on the main thread:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, reponse, error) -> Void in

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

}
```